# How to highlight/mark a domain name which appear in an email address list?

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Spreadsheets I have:

Column A - contain naked domain list(apples.com, banana.com, oranges.com)

Column C - potentially contains email address with those naked domains( jack@banana.com, mike@pineapple.com, michelle@banana.com)

Column C definitely contains column A domains, but not vice versa.

How do I highlight/marl all the email address which contain a naked domain from column A?

And then afterwards get rid of the non-highlighted/marked email addresses? 
Or any pointers where I can find an answer?

Comment: [An hour ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36750198/partial-match-between-two-columns-in-excel-return-value-of-one-column#36750198).

Comment: Conditional Formatting most likely, then a quick VB script to remove non-highlighted cells.  What have you tried? What has/hasn't worked?

Comment: @BruceWayne Nothing to be honest. im a noob with all this. stumbling towards a solution hopefully

Comment: @BruceWayne looks like i should be using the substring feature to separate the domains from the email address first & then compare the two domain lists

Answer (score 0):

#### Highlighting matched emails

(Assuming 1st row is headers), apply conditional formatting to B2:B with **custom formula**

```
=regexmatch(B2, "(" & join("|", filter(A$2:A, len(A$2:A))) & ")$")
```

This will highlight the email addresses ending with one of the strings in A2:A (joining them with `|` creates a regular expression with this effect, and adding $ at the end insists that the match can be only at the end).

#### Keeping only matched emails

It's easier to make a new list than to delete stuff from the old list. This function returns the list of all matching emails:

```
=filter(B2:B, regexmatch(B2:B, "(" & join("|", filter(A$2:A, len(A$2:A))) & ")$"))
```

You can then copy it and paste-as-values where the old list used to be.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do a simple vlookup, using the regexed domain as your search key:

To apply to the whole column:

```
=SORT(IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(REGEXREPLACE(C2:C,".*@",""),A:A,1,0))))
```